При старте проекта npm run server IntellijIdea стал запрашивать доступ к микрофону, контактам и прочему
Мне в формате zip скинули проект на React (и бэк вроде на Node.js). (еще скинули pdf с мокапами проекта). Я сначала заинсталлила все зависимости (npm install) а потом попыталась запустить проект npm run server. Во время сборки мне через какое-то время начали появляться системные окошки, что IntellijIdea запрашивает доступ к Контактам, Микрофону, Галерее и прочему. Я естественно это запрещала и потом вообще прервала сборку через Control+C. Я конечно напугалась, что это вообще такое произошло. Я идею не обновляла давно, и такое поведение впервые наблюдаю. Меня пытались взломать? И как понять, утекло ли что-то
